# Why is spring-boot-starter-mail causing a context error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, spring-boot-starter

ello
I am using SpringBoot to create a web-application and in the relevant code I am allowing a button to be clicked which removes an object from the database, and then sends an email to the email address of that object. Before I added the email part when the button was clicked it worked perfectly and the row was removed from the table, now however I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'restart'

I think it is to do with the context in the controller:
Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/rejectApplicant")
@ResponseBody
public String rejectApplicant(@RequestParam String id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    Long athleteID = Long.parseLong(id);
    Optional<Athlete> optionalAthlete = athleteAuditor.findAthleteById(athleteID);
    Athlete athlete = optionalAthlete.get();
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            EmailConfig.class);
    MailService mailService = context.getBean("mailService", MailServiceImp.class);
    System.out.println("//////         " + mailService.toString());
    String senderEmailId = "Z@gmail.com";
    String receiverEmailId = athlete.getEmail();
    System.out.println("//////         " + receiverEmailId);
    String subject = "Your time at Lyons";
    String message = "Dear " + athlete.getName() + "How goes it?";
    mailService.sendEmail(senderEmailId, receiverEmailId, subject, message);
    context.close();
 athleteAuditor.deleteAthlete(athleteID);
 return "applicants";
}
```

//CONFIG

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "xda")
public class EmailConfig {

u/Bean
 public JavaMailSender getMailSender()
    {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

// Using Gmail SMTP configuration.
 mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);

/*
         * Use your gmail id and password
         */
 mailSender.setUsername("X@gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPassword("Y");

       Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");

       mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
 return mailSender;
    }
}
```

//MAIL SERVICE IMP

```
@Service("mailService")
public class MailServiceImp implements MailService
{

u/Autowired



JavaMailSender mailSender;

public void sendEmail(final String senderEmailId, final String receiverEmailId,
 final String subject, final String message)
    {

       MimeMessagePreparator prep = new MimeMessagePreparator()
        {

public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception
            {
                mimeMessage.setFrom(senderEmailId);
                mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
 new InternetAddress(receiverEmailId));
                mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
                mimeMessage.setText(message);

           }
        };

try
 {
 mailSender.send(prep);
            System.out.println("Successfully sent message");
        }
 catch (Exception exe)
        {
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

//mailService

```
public interface MailService
{
 public void sendEmail(final String senderEmailId, final String receiverEmailId,
 final String subject, final String message);
}
```

Sorry there is so much code, I have no idea what is causing it, it is my first time trying to use Spring-Boot-Starter-Mail, thanks for any help!

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, why are you creating your own `JavaMailSender` instead of using the one you get automatically?

Comment: Your code is flawed to begin with. Don't create a context to obtain a bean, just `@Autowire` it into your controller. Remove the `@CompontScan` and as you are using SPring Boot remove the `EmailConfig` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `@ComponentScan`. I would check if `@ComponentScan` is used just one time. From [Baeldung Spring Component Scanning](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning):

> With Spring, we use the @ComponentScan annotation along with
> @Configuration annotation to specify the packages that we want to be
> scanned. @ComponentScan without arguments tells Spring to scan the
> current package and all of its sub-packages.

> Note that the main application class and the configuration class are
> not necessarily the same. If they are different, it doesn't matter
> where to put the main application class. Only the location of the
> configuration class matters as component scanning starts from its
> package by default.